Kotlin Gradle Multi Module Spring Project Shared Test Dependencies
I was looking a way to create shared test dependencies under test folder in a Kotlin - Gradle - Spring Boot multi module project.
For example:
-parent-module
 -child_1_module
  - scr
    - main
    - test
  - build.gradle.kts
 -child_1_module
  - scr
    - main
    - test
  - build.gradle.kts
 -child_shared_module
  - scr
    - main
    - test
      - com.domain.testUtilities
        - TestUtil.kt
  - build.gradle.kts

This is my structure and I want to use classes from test utilites in chlid 1 and 2 tests. I came upon Gradle's testFixtures but I do not think it works with Kotlin - or I missed something in the config. My implementation for testFixtures was:

Add plug-ins:
 java-library and java-test-fixtures to sharred module
Added dependency to child 1 and 2
testImplementation(testFixtures(project(":child_shared_module")))

Those are the basic instructions I found in Gradles documentation. But still I do not see the the TestUtil in child 1 and 2 tests.
I am using Gradle v8.5 and Kotlin 1.9.22

Try to change folder name from test to testFixture
-child_shared_module
  - scr
    - main
    - testFixture
      - kotlin
        - com.domain.testUtilities
          - TestUtil.kt

It is written so in documentation
Perhaps you intentionally omitted the need for a kotlin folder, but I’ll include it in my example to provide a more complete solution.
